# Phpbb3.1 MyIsam database corrupted

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam, phpbb3

everyone! I'm trying to avoid breaking of my database in the phpbb3.1 forum. It was crushed twice this month. 
So I have two questions:
1) Is it safe to convert MyISAM to InnoDB? I mean will extensions work fine? Will forum be workable after updating to next version?
2) In which way I can avoid base corrupting?

p.s. 
I also posted this question here:
https://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=466&t=2436326

Comment: this question is in no way related to PHP - why did you tag it? also: the whole question is about database administration - which is **not** coding.

Comment: I thought phpbb is related with PHP

Comment: yes. but your **question** is not. it would have been if you were asking about something specific in code you had written for it, but not if you just ask about how to use it.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann - Or is it?  What part of the system is "crashing".  Please elaborate on "crash".

Comment: [_Here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb) are some tips on converting from MyISAM to InnoDB.  (No there is nothing about "crashing".)

Comment: Oh, it "was crushed", it did not "crash".  Now I am lost.

Comment: @Franz Gleichmann, I understand, thank you!

Comment: @RickJames, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'll venture a guess.  You had a power failure, and when it came back up, MySQL was complaining that some index on some table was corrupted?  And that table was MyISAM?

1. Use `myisamchk` to repair the tables.
2. Review the gotchas in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb to see if conversion to InnoDB will add new woes.  There probably won't be any.  A 2-part `PRIMARY KEY` is about the only thing that is not implemented in InnoDB.  Also, if you have too old a version of MySQL, InnoDB may not yet have `FULLTEXT` indexes (if you need them).
3. Change my.cnf:  `key_buffer_size = 20M` and `innodb_buffer_pool_size` equal to about half of *available* memory.
4. `ALTER TABLE xx ENGINE=InnoDB;` for each table `xx`.

I think (but am not sure) that each update/delete/insert marks the table as possibly corrupt.  It writes the changes, but does not clear the mark.  When mysqld shuts down cleanly, everything is flushed to disk and these flags are cleared.  When mysqld comes back up, it complains about the flags that did not get cleared.  So...

Whether or not an index is marked as corrupt depends solely on whether you modified that index and crashed.  (Every table has some index, yes?)

Normally, MySQL manages to flush changes to disk before a crash.  Only occasionally does the crash happen at a time where the index will really be corrupt.  There is a "quick" mode on the repair that simply clears the flag -- you could try that.  But if you ever get a mysterious "can't find record" when you know the records exists, you'd better `REPAIR` it.

Comment: @youngB -- suggest you post my link on the PHPBB forum so they can ponder whether there are potential issues.

Comment: Thank for your replay. 
I have another question to the 3-rd point in this steps. 
If "key_buffer_size" and "innodb_buffer_pool_size" already have bigger values than you advise,  should I make any changes?

Comment: They are the main memory allocation parameters.  If they add up to too much, you could be "swapping", which is _terrible_ for performance.  Key_buffer is needed for MyISAM; the other is for InnoDB.  However, key_buffer should not be zero even when entirely InnoDB.  If you have more than 4GB of RAM, 70% of ram is advised for InnoDB's buffer_pool.

Comment: @ Rick James, Thanks again.
Could you please tell me about the reason of base corrupting if you have any ideas? 
I noticed session tables has fewer records than other tables,  and it corrupts more often than another match bigger tables.   That's mean the number of records has not any effect on this problem.

Comment: @youngB - I added a few paragraphs.  I suspect it is not table size, but table activity that correlates with 'corruption'.

Comment: @ Rick James, 
Ok. thank you. I think this question could be closed. Unless I will publish more detailed reasons for my problem.